# function error then using i ++ for dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to have a tab system dynamic . . .

For this I am giving a value to my id to make it dynamic using i ++

thsi way the tab and the tab_content can be call having the same id.

I'm using the below:

```
var tabtoggle = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-link');

for (var i = 0; i < tabtoggle.length; i++)
tabtoggle[i].id = 'tab-link' + i;


$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).id('tab-link' + i);

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```

But on clicking the tab, my console say than I've an error in 
`var tab_id = $(this).id('tab-link' + i);`

Than the function does not exist

Any help ? It will be superb

Thank you

Comment: There is no `.id`.

Comment: sorry ? what should it be instead ? Thank you :)

Comment: what are you expecting `var tab_id = $(this).id('tab-link' + i);` to do? it looks like you are trying to assign and retrieve a value at the same time?

Comment: An `id` should also be unique